# HBase coprocessor not updating after redeploy

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm using HBase 1.1.2, and trying to redeploy a custom endpoint coprocessor to fix an error in my Java code. I made some changes to the coprocessor code and redeployed it via the following steps:

1. Rebuild the coprocessor jar
2. Copy it to a location on the HDFS
3. Remove the existing coprocessor: `alter 'table', METHOD => 'table_att_unset',NAME => 'coprocessor$1'`
4. Confirm through the HBase UI that the table has no coprocessors attached
5. Add the new coprocessor by disabling the table and running `alter 'table', METHOD => 'table_att', 'coprocessor'=>'hdfs:///user/bwatson/sum-coprocessor-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar|uk.co.hadoopathome.coprocessor.SumAndCountEndpoint||'`
6. Re-enable the table
7. Confirm through the HBase UI that the coprocessor has been attached

When I re-run my client code that talks to the coprocessor, I can clearly see in the regionserver logs that the old coprocessor code is still running.

If I search for the jar locally on the regionserver that hosts my table, I see that the jar is only in one location:

```
find / -name "*um-coprocesso*"
/tmp/hbase-hbase/local/jars/tmp/.2107072457.sum-coprocessor-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.1522237762363.jar
/tmp/hbase-hbase/local/jars/tmp/..2107072457.sum-coprocessor-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.1522237762363.jar.crc
```

I can confirm from the date and size of this jar that it is the old version.

Is this a bug in HBase? How can I get around this?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that https://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/hbase-coprocessors says that the above is a dynamic method for deploying coprocessors, and shouldn't require a restart of HBase. I don't have permissions at work to restart HBase so have raised a request and will see if that changes anything.

Comment: I would suggest you to try after updating the version of the jar to avoid any kind of caching issue. e.g. `*sum-coprocessor-0.2.0*`

Comment: I hope that the path `hdfs:///user/bwatson/sum-coprocessor-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` is correct (I have usually found them as `hdfs://localhost/user...` or `hdfs://<domain>/<folder>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting HBase did the trick; the jar in `/tmp/hbase-hbase/local/jars/tmp/` was removed, and my next deploy was successful.

This is a bug in HBase, either in the documentation or the code. I'll raise a ticket with the HBase Jira.

Answer (score 0):

you need to restart hbase server.

```
cd $HBASE_HOME/bin
$sh stop-hbase.sh
$sh start-hbase.sh
```

you cann't change coprocessor jar file when hbase is running. so you should restart hbase server after your step 6.